# regular expression search backwards, How to deal with words with and without?

Tags: regex, python-re

I tested by https://regexr.com/
There two sample words.

```
BOND_aa_SB1_66-1.pdf

BOND_bb_SB2.pdf
```

I want to extract SB1, SB2 from each sample.
but my regular expression is not perfect.

It is working

```
(?<=BOND_.*_).*
```

But It is difficult to write the following.

I try

```
(?<=BOND_.*_).*(?=(_|\.))
```

But first sample result is 'SB1_66-1'

I just want to extract SB1

sb1 The following may or may not exist. if there is content, it can be separated by starting with _.

How should I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

To extract the *third* underscore-separated term, we can use `re.search` as follows:

```py
inp = ["BOND_aa_SB1_66-1.pdf", "BOND_bb_SB2.pdf"]
output = [re.search(r'^BOND_[^_]+_([^_.]+)', x).group(1) for x in inp]
print(output)  # ['SB1', 'SB2']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "BOND_aa_SB1_66-1.pdf BOND_bb_SB2.pdf"

(re.findall(r'(SB\d+)', s))

['SB1', 'SB2']
```

Comment: thank you However, the contents of the SB location are subject to change! So I'm looking for a way to separate them with '_' . It's not always SB. Sorry for my lack of examples.

Comment: @younghyun. re.findall will find SB\d in any location.